# How do I format a range of pgfplotstable columns at once?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I want to set a range of columns (1,2,3 in the MWE below) at once without overwriting the formatting of the first column. Therefore, I don't think an "all" columns solution is applicable.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
hi,0.563725,0.819520,0.713402
guys,0.563725,0.819520,0.713402
\end{filecontents}

\sisetup{
  round-mode          = places,
  round-precision     = 2,
}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
      col sep=comma,
      display columns/0/.style={string type},
      display columns/1/.style={column type={S},string type},
      display columns/2/.style={column type={S},string type},
      display columns/3/.style={column type={S},string type}
    ]{data.csv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can construct your multi setter

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
hi,0.563725,0.819520,0.713402
guys,0.563725,0.819520,0.713402
\end{filecontents}

\sisetup{
  round-mode          = places,
  round-precision     = 2,
}

\pgfplotstableset{
  my multistyler/.style 2 args={
    @my multistyler/.style={display columns/##1/.append style={#2}},
    @my multistyler/.list={#1}
  }
}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[ 
      col sep=comma,
      my multistyler={0,...,3}{string type},
      my multistyler={1,2,3}{column type={S}}
    ]{data.csv}
\end{document}
```

[image]