# Set column or row style for more than one row tikzset

Tags: tikz-styles

I am using Tikzset to set the attributes of rows and columns in a matrix of nodes. I can figure out how to effect either "every column" or "column 1" but I cant figure out how to with one command effect a list of columns. Here is what works to set style for one column.

```
\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
column 1/.style={
            nodes={
            text width = 1em
            }}
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (comp) [table,matrix of nodes]
    {
     cell1 & cell2 &cell3  \\
     cell2 & cell3 &cell4  \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What I would like to be able to set attributes for column 1 and 2 and this does not work:

```
\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
column {1,2}/.style={
            nodes={
            text width = 1em
            }}
}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (comp) [table,matrix of nodes]
    {
     cell1 & cell2 &cell3  \\
     cell2 & cell3 &cell4  \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: See this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272512/how-do-i-format-a-range-of-pgfplotstable-columns-at-once It is for pgfplotstable but uses the same `/.style` and `/.list` construction

Comment: @percusse That's a really cool trick!

Comment: clairekelly: In case you find @percusse nice trick not obvious: try `\tikzset{ 
 my multistyler/.style 2 args={
    @my multistyler/.style={column ##1/.append style={#2}},
    @my multistyler/.list={#1}
  }
}` and then `\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (comp) [matrix of nodes,my multistyler={1,3}{text width=1em}]
    {
     cell1 & cell2 &cell3 & cell5 & cell7 \\
     cell2 & cell3 &cell4 & cell6 & cell8 \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @marmot Write an answer :)

Comment: @marmot your solution works!

Comment: @percusse perhaps you should write the answer since it’s your trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is @percusse's solution, and I will be very happy to retract "my" answer if he wants to add his. In any case, this is just a copy of [@percusse's original answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272512/how-do-i-format-a-range-of-pgfplotstable-columns-at-once), so if you read this and find it useful, upvote his and not "mine". The following two styles are, of course, equivalent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{my multistyler/.style 2 args={
    @my multistyler/.style={column ##1/.append style={#2}},
    @my multistyler/.list={#1}
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (comp) [matrix of nodes,my multistyler={1,3}{text width=1em}]
    {
     cell1 & cell2 &cell3 & cell5 & cell7 \\
     cell2 & cell3 &cell4 & cell6 & cell8 \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}


\tikzset{table/.style={my multistyler={1,3}{text width=1em}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (comp) [matrix of nodes,table]
    {
     cell1 & cell2 &cell3 & cell5 & cell7 \\
     cell2 & cell3 &cell4 & cell6 & cell8 \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm often away from a TeX distro and overleaf is tedious to write an answer. So no worries :)

Comment: @percusse I am still stunned by your nice trick. Do you have a secret manual for this? ;-)

Comment: Getting stuck in a PhD for a few years helps :)

Comment: @percusse Life after PhD is not necessarily easier. As is well known, the first part of your academic life gets spoiled by the advisor, and the second part by the students ;-)