# How should I draw a linked list each node pointed by additional node

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, diagrams

I would like draw a linked-list example as on the following figure. Idea is similiar to solution for [How should I draw a singly/double linked list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19288/127048), but I wasn't able to do the arrowing from north node to south node.

[image]

I have used following example for [How to make a graph (nodes and edges) on Latex?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56319928/2402577) .

- I was not able to put the labes next to boxes, followed by a dash to point  them. Also dashed rectangle that covers the three boxes at top.

Minimal code that I tried:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows} % Shadows for nodes
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{% This is the style settings for nodes
    dep/.style={square,minimum size=1cm,fill=orange!20,draw=orange,
      general shadow={fill=gray!60,shadow xshift=1pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}},
    cli/.style={square,minimum size=1cm,fill=white,draw,
      general shadow={fill=gray!60,shadow xshift=1pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}},
    spl/.style={square,append after command={
        node[circle,draw,dotted,
        minimum size=1.5cm] at (\tikzlastnode.center) {}}},
    c1/.style={-stealth,very thick,black!80!black},
    v2/.style={-stealth,very thick,yellow!65!black},
    v4/.style={-stealth,very thick,purple!70!black}}
  \node[dep] (1) at (0,0) {0};
  \node[dep] (2) at (2,0) {4};
  \node[dep] (3) at (4,0) {10};
   %
  \node[cli] (16) at (6,0) {tail};

  \node[cli] (7) at (0,-2) {-16};
  \node[cli] (8) at (2,-2) {-16};
  \node[cli] (9) at (4,-2) {-16};
  %
  \node[cli] (10) at (0,-3) {3};
  \node[cli] (11) at (2,-3) {10};
  \node[cli] (12) at (4,-3) {15};
  %
  \node[dep] (13) at (0,-4) {4};
  \node[dep] (14) at (2,-4) {10};
  \node[cli] (15) at (4,-4) {/};

  \draw[c1] (1) -- (7);
  \draw[c1] (2) -- (8);
  \draw[c1] (3) -- (9);
  \draw[c1] (16) -- (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of just posting the image, can you edit your question to show a minimal document with what you've tried? Then people can more easily help you with the parts you're having difficulty with.

Comment: Thanks! Where is your `square` style defined?

Comment: I belive its `dep` (with color) and `cli` (without color) ; their aliases' might be confusing because I haven't changed them from the original example

Comment: The code as posted doesn't compile, because `square` isn't defined.

Comment: Ah I have no idea why it compiles on my end ; I just wanted to draw a square

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually anything that looks like a matrix can be made more easily with a TikZ matrix. And usually a TikZ matrix is ​​easier than the cumbersome placement of single nodes.

**1. The picture from the startpost:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
>=stealth, 
]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,  nodes in empty cells,
nodes={draw, %thick, 
%inner sep=0pt,   outer sep=0pt,
%minimum width=1.9em,
text height=\ht\strutbox,
text depth=\dp\strutbox,
text width =1.5\ht\strutbox,
align=center, anchor=center,
}, 
column sep=1em, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
Fill/.style 2 args={row #1 column #2/.style={nodes={fill=cyan!66}}},
Fill/.list={ {5}{2}, {5}{3} },
row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}  },
column 1/.style={column sep=2em,
nodes={align=right, draw=none, text width=1cm}  },
%
row 2 column 1/.style={nodes={xshift=-2mm}},
%
column 5/.style={nodes={draw=none}  },
row 2 column 5/.style={nodes={draw}  },
%
row 2/.style={row sep=1.5em,   },
%
column 4/.style={column sep=1.75em,   },
]{
          &         &        &        &  tail   \\
mapping   &  0      &  4     &  10    & 10       \\
value     &  -16    &  -16   &  -16   &          \\
point     &  3      &  10    &  15    &           \\
next      &  4      &  10    &  /     &            \\
%1  &  2   &  3   &  4   &  5   \\
};

% Annotations:
\foreach \col in {2,...,4}{
\draw[->] (m-2-\col) -- (m-3-\col);     }
\draw[->] (m-2-5) -- (m-2-4);

\foreach \row in {3,...,5}{
\draw[shorten >=2pt] (m-\row-1) -- (m-\row-2);     }

\draw[shorten >=1em] (m-2-1) -- (m-2-2);     
    
\draw[densely dashed] ([shift={(-0.5em,0.5em)}]m-2-2.north west) rectangle ([shift={(0.5em,-0.5em)}]m-2-\lastcolP.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**2. With variable numbers of rows and columns:**

There is no key like `row last/.style=...` so you need to create them and then use some tricks due to the expanding order:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{store number of columns in/.style={execute at end matrix={
\xdef#1{\the\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns}}},
store number of rows in/.style={execute at end matrix={
\xdef#1{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% Wrong start values
\def\lastrow{1}
\def\lastcol{1}
\def\lastcolP{1}
\newcommand\mymatrix{%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
>=stealth, 
]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,  nodes in empty cells,
store number of columns in=\lastcol,
store number of rows in=\lastrow,
ampersand replacement=\&, 
nodes={draw, %thick, 
inner sep=0pt,   outer sep=0pt,
minimum width=1.9em,
text height=\ht\strutbox,
text depth=\dp\strutbox,
text width =1.5\ht\strutbox,
align=center, anchor=center,
}, 
column sep=1em, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
]{
       \&    \&      \&     \&        \&  tail   \\
mapping\&  0 \&  4   \& new  \&  1    \&  10    \\
value  \&  -16  \&  -16 \& new  \&  -16  \&   \\
point  \&  3   \&  10  \& new   \&  15   \&     \\
new    \& new  \&  new   \& new \&  new  \&     \\  
new    \& new  \&  new   \& new \&  new  \&     \\  
new    \& new  \&  new   \& new \&  new  \&     \\  
next   \&  4      \&  10       \& new     \&  /  \&   \\
%1  \&  2   \&  3   \&  4   \&  5   \& 6 \\
};
%
% Annotations:
\foreach \col in {2,...,\lastcolP}{
\draw[->] (m-2-\col) -- (m-3-\col);     }
\draw[->] (m-2-\lastcol) -- (m-2-\lastcolP);

\foreach \row in {3,...,\lastrow}{
\draw[shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt] (m-\row-1) -- (m-\row-2);     }

\draw[shorten >=0.7em, shorten <=3pt] (m-2-1) -- (m-2-2);     

\draw[densely dashed] ([shift={(-0.5em,0.5em)}]m-2-2.north west) rectangle ([shift={(0.5em,-0.5em)}]m-2-\lastcolP.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}%%%

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{\mymatrix}

\section{Wrong} 
\mymatrix 

\section{Still Wrong} 
\usebox{\mybox} \par
Last col is: \lastcol.  Last row is \lastrow. 


\pgfmathtruncatemacro\lastcolP{\lastcol-1}
\tikzset{
store number of columns in=\lastcol,
store number of rows in=\lastrow,
Fill/.style 2 args={row #1 column #2/.style={nodes={fill=cyan!44}}},
Fill/.list={ {\lastrow}{2}, {\lastrow}{3} },
row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none}  },
column 1/.style={column sep=2em,
nodes={align=right, draw=none, text width=1cm}  },
%
row 2 column 1/.style={nodes={xshift=-2mm}},
%
column \lastcol/.style={nodes={draw=none}  },
row 2 column \lastcol/.style={nodes={draw}  },
%
row 2/.style={row sep=1.5em,   },
%
column \lastcolP/.style={column sep=1.75em,   },
}

\section{Correct} 
\savebox{\mybox}{\mymatrix}
\usebox{\mybox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why is the lines between boxes are bolder than the original line width? What should I do if I add additional value,point,next boxes ; like should I change `column 4` to `column 5` ?

Comment: Can I set column number into a variable as well ?

Comment: Just use `row sep=-\pgflinewidth,` (see edit). At the other points, I do not know exactly what you are meaning. But you can everytime open new questions, with a reduced MWE that focusses on that point.

Comment: BTW: There can be some differences between the preview of TeXworks and a real PDF-viewer. Normally the lines should not have different thicknesses, if you haven't set.

Comment: Thanks I had also difficulties to add an additional column and when I add it ; which variables should I update like `column 4` ... ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Also it is possible to descrease the space between `tail` string and the box ?

Comment: You can set this `column sep` whatever you want...

Comment: See new answer with savebox etc.

Comment: That's magic ! Thanks for adding the adding new boxes and handling the new column size

Comment: Sorry I get little lost in the code; is it possible the add `cyan` color to top boxes that are: `0`, `4`, `new`, and `1` ? (first row, except the tail box)

Comment: Also I was not able to fit 4 digits like `-123` into a box it shows up as only `-` ; can I make font size smaller for only 4 digit strings? like I can add `1234` but having `-` at the beginning does not allow me to print out the numbers

Comment: There is `Fill/.list={ {5}{2}, {5}{3}, .....,    {Row No.}{Col No.}, .... },` where you can fill cells. The rest are elementary TikZ-questions, I think. You should learn this step by step and not all together in one giant example. So open various individual questions, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks @cis ; can you recemmoned any guide to learn ? I am trying to handle trial/error on your code :-) For example: how can I move the box that has `T` on its above to top of `mapping` string and make its arrow to point box that has 3 in it?

Comment: For the origin of some of the keys that were used without reference see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272543 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/493744.

Comment: For `\savebox{\mybox}{\mymatrix}` I start to  get following error: `! Misplaced alignment tab character &.
\pgf@matrix@cell@cont ...st@nextcell@options {#1}&` is it a normal case?
`

Comment: @alper I was long time ago, but I checked the code and it works at mine.

Comment: Ah my editor convert all `\&` into `\    &` which was causing the problem

Answer (score 7):

This is not really an answer but I agree with [this answer by pikopiko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569219/227987) that it is better not position anything by hand. So out of many possibilities that allow you to avoid manual positioning here is one using a `matrix`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix,positioning,shadows} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\sansmath,
    square/.style={minimum size=1cm,draw,fill=white,drop shadow},
    f/.style={fill=orange!20,draw=orange},
    v2/.style={-stealth,very thick,yellow!65!black}]
 \matrix[matrix of math nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=1.5em,
 cells={nodes={square,
    text depth=0.25ex,text height=1em}},
 row 1/.style={nodes=f}] (m){
  0 & 4 & 10 \\[2em]
  -16 & -16 & -16\\
  3 & 10 & 15\\
  |[f]|4 & |[f]|10 & /\\
 };
 %
 \node[draw,dashed,inner sep=1em,fit=(m-1-1)(m-1-3)](f){};
 %
 \node[square,right=3em of m-1-3] (t){tail};
 %
 \foreach \x[count=\y] in {mapping,value,point,next}
 {\draw \ifnum\y=1 (f.west)
 \else
 (m-\y-1.west)\fi -- ++ (-2em,0) node[left]{\x};}
 %
 \draw[v2] (t) -- (m-1-3);
 \foreach \x in {1,2,3}
 {\draw[v2] (m-1-\x) -- (m-2-\x);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to give a small space between the box and like that points the label?

Comment: @alper Yes. Use: `\foreach \x[count=\y] in {mapping,value,point,next}
 {\draw[shorten <=1ex] \ifnum\y=1 (f.west)
 \else
 (m-\y-1.west)\fi -- ++ (-2em,0) node[left]{\x};}`

Comment: @alper To drop the shadows you need to drop `drop shadow`.

Comment: Sorry for simple questions, how can I write `tail` above of the box that has `tail` string ?

Comment: @alper You can use `label`: `\node[square,right=3em of m-1-3,label=above:tail] (t){$10$};`.

Comment: If I add additional column lets say 2 more; is there any way to store to column value in a variable and by changing it might handle all the related column sets.

Comment: @alper Do you mean something like `column 4/.style={nodes={...}}`? You can also define `\def\icol{4}` and then use in the options of the matrix `column \icol/.style={nodes={fill=blue}}`.

Comment: I am not that familiar with this syntax but yes; like instead of `1-4` I want to say `1-column` handling all related column values but not sure is it possible or not

Comment: @alper `column 4/.style={nodes={...}}` affects all the nodes in column 4. These options are surveyed in section **20.3.3 Cell Styles and Options** of pgfmanual v3.1.6. If you have a concrete example I could possibly say more. You may be looking for the things discussed on the top of p. 327.

Comment: On @cis's answer boxes are more compact (less empty space in the box)  ; is it possible to have the same behavior on your code as well ? I play around but not sure what causes this

Comment: @alper I copied `minimum size=1cm` from your post. In cis code you'll find `text height=\ht\strutbox,
text depth=\dp\strutbox,
text width =1.5\ht\strutbox,`. So, yes, you can obviously change this. Just drop  `minimum size=1cm` and replace it by whatever width, height and depth you find appropriate (and drop `text depth=0.25ex,text height=1em` from the styles in the matrix).

Answer (score 4):

Here you go, I'm using the `positioning` library to achieve it without a bunch of extra commands setting up coordinates.

Your code had an error with the `square` style; I removed the term `square' as it appears to not do anything to your code.

I've included the text above the tail box in case you wish to use it (as I see you've already written 'tail' inside the box).

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows, positioning} % Shadows for nodes
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{% This is the style settings for nodes
    dep/.style={minimum size=1cm,fill=orange!20,draw=orange,
      general shadow={fill=gray!60,shadow xshift=1pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}},
    cli/.style={minimum size=1cm,fill=white,draw,
      general shadow={fill=gray!60,shadow xshift=1pt,shadow yshift=-1pt}},
    spl/.style={append after command={
        node[circle,draw,dotted,
        minimum size=1.5cm] at (\tikzlastnode.center) {}}},
    c1/.style={-stealth,very thick,black!80!black},
    v2/.style={-stealth,very thick,yellow!65!black},
    v4/.style={-stealth,very thick,purple!70!black}}
  \node[dep] (1) at (0,0) {0};
  \node[dep] (2) at (2,0) {4};
  \node[dep] (3) at (4,0) {10};
   %
  \node[cli] (16) at (6,0) {tail};

  \node[cli] (7) at (0,-2) {-16};
  \node[cli] (8) at (2,-2) {-16};
  \node[cli] (9) at (4,-2) {-16};
  %
  \node[cli] (10) at (0,-3) {3};
  \node[cli] (11) at (2,-3) {10};
  \node[cli] (12) at (4,-3) {15};
  %
  \node[dep] (13) at (0,-4) {4};
  \node[dep] (14) at (2,-4) {10};
  \node[cli] (15) at (4,-4) {/};

  \draw[c1] (1) -- (7);
  \draw[c1] (2) -- (8);
  \draw[c1] (3) -- (9);
  \draw[c1] (16) -- (3);
  
  % label lines next to boxes
  
  \node[left = 0.3cm of 1] (labellineTop){};
  \node[left = 0.3cm of 7] (labelline1){};
  \node[left = 0.3cm of 10] (labelline2){};
  \node[left = 0.3cm of 13] (labelline3){};
  
  \draw (labelline1) -- +(-1,0);
  \draw (labelline2) -- +(-1,0);
  \draw (labelline3) -- +(-1,0);
  \draw (labellineTop) -- +(-1,0);
  
  % labels next to boxes
  
  \node[left = 1.5cm of 1, align=right] {mapping};
  \node[left = 1.5cm of 7, align=right] {value};
  \node[left = 1.5cm of 10, align=right] {point};
  \node[left = 1.5cm of 13, align=right] {next};
  \node[above = 0.2cm of 16] {tail};
  
  % dashed rectangle
  
  \node[above left = 0.3cm of 1] (rectangleA){};
  \node[below right = 0.3cm of 3] (rectangleB){};
  \draw[dashed] (rectangleA) rectangle (rectangleB){};
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```