# How could I draw arrows in between bottom cells in a linked-list

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, diagrams

I have applied following answer for [How should I draw a linked list each node pointed by additional node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/569227/127048) (I am using the exact code on the answer). But I was not able to manage to draw arrows in between cells.

I was wondering how could I draw arrows in between bottom cells:

Example:

[image]

---

Example for arrow passing on top of a inner arrow (assume there is a cell):

[image]

---

In case arrow exists from a cell that an another arrow already entered they overwrite on top of each other, is it possible shif them so they won't be drawn on top of each other while keeping same height for them.

[image]

with following code:

```
      \coordinate[below=of m-3-7](aux);
      \draw[->](m-5-7)--(aux)-|(m-5-5);

      \coordinate[below=of m-3-5](aux);
      \draw[->](m-5-5)--(aux)-|(m-5-3);
```

But I want lines not to overwrite on top of each other, example:

[image]

Comment: please have a look a the answer below -- add  the following lines to your code at the end -- `\coordinate[below=of m-4-1](aux);
  \draw[v2](m-4-1)--(aux)-|(m-4-3);`  -the first line creates a coordinate below the  node 4 -- the second line draws the arrow down to the coordinate `aux` and then right to the node / -- the matrix auto names for the fourth row as follows -- `m-4-1, m-4-2, m-4-3`

Comment: make it below = 2cm--   or 3cm -- you can experiment to shift down or up

Comment: Thanks what do you mean by `shift down or up` ? is it possible to shift right or left like its height will be same but arrow will be enter into right of the center and exit from left of the center of the cell

Comment: please show a sketch of the desired output -- your question is not clear

Comment: @jsbibra Thanks for your guide, I just want arrows not to overwrite on top of each other, please see an desire output sketch at bottom of my question

Comment: please have a look at the new answer

Comment: I have following code piece from the accepted answer (https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/4abc57a82384793cd23950a32dec8b38) your solution does not work on this answer and Latex keep gives a compilation error not sure why as `Package tikz Error: You need to say \usetikzlibrary{calc} for coordinate calculation.`

Comment: Should `\draw[v2]` be `\draw[->]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix,positioning,shadows, calc} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\sansmath,
        square/.style={minimum size=1cm,draw,fill=white,drop shadow},
        f/.style={fill=orange!20,draw=orange},
        v2/.style={-stealth,very thick,yellow!65!black}]
        \matrix[matrix of math nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=1.5em,
        cells={nodes={square,
                text depth=0.25ex,text height=1em}},
        row 1/.style={nodes=f}] (m){
            0 & 4 & 10 \\[2em]
            -16 & -16 & -16\\
            3 & 10 & 15\\
            |[f]|4 & |[f]|10 & /\\
        };
        %
        \node[draw,dashed,inner sep=1em,fit=(m-1-1)(m-1-3)](f){};
        %
        \node[square,right=3em of m-1-3] (t){tail};
        %
        \foreach \x[count=\y] in {mapping,value,point,next}
        {\draw \ifnum\y=1 (f.west)
            \else
            (m-\y-1.west)\fi -- ++ (-2em,0) node[left]{\x};}
        %
        \draw[v2] (t) -- (m-1-3);
        \foreach \x in {1,2,3}
        {\draw[v2] (m-1-\x) -- (m-2-\x);}
        
        \coordinate[below=of m-4-1](aux);
        \draw[v2](m-4-1)--(aux)-|(m-4-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

changing the last two lines

```
\coordinate[below=of m-4-2](aux);
        \draw[v2](m-4-2)--(aux)-|(m-4-3);
```

will give

[image]

to place an additional node in the fourth row with arrow add the following code

```
\node[square,right=3em of m-4-3] (q){};
         \coordinate[below=1.5cm of m-4-1](auxx);
         \draw[v2](m-4-1)--(auxx)-|(q);
```

[image]

**EDIT new answer**

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3]{standalone}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix,positioning,shadows, calc} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\sansmath,
        square/.style={minimum size=1cm,draw,fill=white,drop shadow},
        f/.style={fill=orange!20,draw=orange},
        v2/.style={-stealth,very thick,yellow!65!black}]
        \matrix[matrix of math nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=1.5em,
        cells={nodes={square,
                text depth=0.25ex,text height=1em}},
        row 1/.style={nodes=f}] (m){
            0 & 4 & 10 \\[2em]
            -16 & -16 & -16\\
            3 & 10 & 15\\
            |[f]|4 & |[f]|10 & /\\
        };
        %
        \node[draw,dashed,inner sep=1em,fit=(m-1-1)(m-1-3)](f){};
        %
        \node[square,right=3em of m-1-3] (t){tail};
        %
        \foreach \x[count=\y] in {mapping,value,point,next}
        {\draw \ifnum\y=1 (f.west)
            \else
            (m-\y-1.west)\fi -- ++ (-2em,0) node[left]{\x};}
        %
        \draw[v2] (t) -- (m-1-3);
        \foreach \x in {1,2,3}
        {\draw[v2] (m-1-\x) -- (m-2-\x);}
        
        \coordinate[below=of m-4-1](aux);
        \draw[v2](m-4-1)--(aux)-|(m-4-3);
\draw[v2](m-4-1.east)--(m-4-2.west);
\draw[v2]($(m-4-1.south)+(1ex,0ex)$) -- ($(m-4-1.south)+(1ex,-3ex)$)-|($(m-4-2.south)$);

\draw[v2]($(m-4-2.south)+(1ex,0ex)$) -- ($(m-4-2.south)+(1ex,-3ex)$)-|($(m-4-3.south)+(-2ex,0pt)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On my end the arrow end is not shown and gives a compilation error. I was using @cis's solution where the latest code piece on his answer.  I am also facing if an arrow exits from the same cell than another arrow entered , they on top of each other

Comment: note that you can avoid overlap by using `below = 1,5cm` in the code 
 `\coordinate[below=1.5cm of m-4-1](auxx);` -- this will shift the arrow down -- you can also use above, below right etc -- have a look at he tikz manual if possible

Comment: instead of below is there right or left option? even below works still the arrow are drawn on top of each other, maybe sliding little bit to left/right

Comment: Very nice and my compliments for your 10k.

Comment: @Sebastiano thank you Sir, it is all because of your guidance and all other veterans of this site

Comment: A nice suggestion. Don't follow me, I'm a very poor user. ahahahah.