# How do I format a range of pgfplotstable columns individually

Tags: pgfplotstable

here [How do I format a range of pgfplotstable columns at once?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272512/how-do-i-format-a-range-of-pgfplotstable-columns-at-once/697217#697217)

the code is very clever assigning formatting to selected cells. however, I would like to set individual formatting to selected cells, inside an environment, that is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\pgfplotstableset{%
    col sep = comma,
    header = has colnames,
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule \rowcolor{gray!30},after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
    string type,
    my multistyler/.style 2 args={
        @my multistyler/.style={display columns/##1/.append style={#2}}, %code to be changed
        @my multistyler/.list={#1}
  }
}

\newenvironment{mytable}[5]{%
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
    my multistyler={#4}{column type={p{#5cm}}} %code to be changed
    ]{#1}
    \caption{#2}
    \label{#3}
    \end{table}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytable}{myfile.csv}{caption}{label}{0,1}{6,5}
\end{mytable}
\end{document}
```

this would assign to columns 0 and 1, 6 and 5 cm width respectively.

Comment: Welcome. // Please add what's missing so we can copy, compile and improve your code. I.e. it has to start with \documentclass and end with \end{document}. Thank you

Comment: added as per request